# std::list, std::vector methods and malloc()

Tags: c++, stl

Working with stl:list and stl::vector types under interrupt handlers I want to avoid malloc() calls.

The question: What is a best way to prevent malloc() calls in STL list and vector? Is it enough to create structure with predefined size and then avoid push/pop/erase calls?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Note that the namespace that contains these templates is called std, not stl.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a testimonial: we use two methods mentioned in other answers at my workplace:

- **custom allocators**: for our memory leak tracking system, our instrumenting profiler, and a few other systems, we preallocate and/or "pool" (see e.g. boost::pool) allocs using a provided Allocator -- usually for std::set or std::map, but the principle is the same for std::list.
- **reserve/resize**: for std::vectors, it's very common practice for us to reserve or resize (the difference is important, but both can help avoid future allocs) ahead of time.

Mostly we do these two things to avoid fragmentation, decrease allocator overhead, eliminate the copy-on-grow penalty, etc.  But sometimes (especially with e.g. the instrumenting profiler) we want to absolutely avoid allocation during an interrupt handler.

Usually, however, we avoid issues with interrupts and allocations in other manners:

- **get in/get out**: try to avoid doing anything other than setting flags or trivial copies during interrupts; some times a static (or preallocated) buffer is a far better solution than a STL container.  Holding interrupts for too long is usually a recipe for disaster.
- **disable interrupts during alloc/free**: interrupts are queued up while we're allocating/freeing, instead of being dispatched immediately -- it's a feature of the CPU we're working with.  Combined with a policy of selectively increasing the scope of that disabling/queuing (around e.g. std::list manipulation), we can sometimes get away with a interrupt-handler-as-producer, everything-else-as-consumer model, without overriding the allocator.  If we're in the middle of consuming something from a std::list (e.g. a message received from the network hardware), interrupts are queued for as short a period as possible while pop off a copy of what we're about to process.

Note that lock-free data structures could be an alternative to the second bullet here, we haven't set up and done profiling to see if it would help.  Designing your own is tricky business anyway.

Paranoia is the better part of valor for interrupt handlers: if you're not certain what you're doing will work, it's sometimes much better to approach the issue in an entirely different manner.

Comment: Please note that a lot of this is *very* architecture- and compiler-specific!  It may not apply to many people...

Answer (score 15):

STL containers like `std::list` and `std::vector` have constructors accepting an `Allocator` type. By supplying your own allocator instead of using the default you are able to control how the container allocates memory. This option is rarely used, but using your own allocator in a real time environment is a good example of where this feature is useful (and proves that the designers of STL did a very good job).

The requirements for you custom allocator type is described in 20.1.6 in the [C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1905.pdf)

Answer (score 8):

It sounds like you want to preallocate memory in your initialization code, so that your interrupt handler can avoid heap allocations. I'll assume that the elements you're storing in these containers do not themselves perform any heap allocations, because that would complicate the answer.

You can preallocate memory for `std::vector` by calling the `reserve()` method. Methods like `push_back()`, `pop()`, `insert()`, and `erase()` manipulate the vector's size (the number of elements it currently contains). They only affect the capacity (the number of elements it has room for) when the new size is larger than the current capacity. `reserve(x)` ensures that the capacity is greater or equal to `x`, increasing the capacity if necessary. (Also note that the only operation that ever decreases a vector's capacity is `swap()`, so you don't have to worry about `erase()` reducing the vector's capacity.)

This approach won't work for `std::list`, but there's another approach that will: preallocate list elements by inserting them into a "spare" list. Instead of inserting new elements, use the `splice()` method to move them from the "spare" list to the "primary" list. Instead of erasing elements, use the `splice()` method to move them from the "primary" list to the "spare" list.

Comment: Neat, I hadn't thought of using splice() this way.

Answer (score 3):

Just one other thing to add: a `const std::vector`  will not cause allocations.  So if your interrupt handling code doesn't change the vector, declare it `const` and the compiler will make the `vector` stays the same.

Answer (score 2):

As [onebyone.livejournal.com mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149994/stdlist-stdvector-methods-and-malloc/1150124#1150124), the C++ standard does not say anything about *interrupt* handlers.  It does talk about *signal* handlers, but even then it's a very gray area.  About the only thing you can do inside a signal handler that's guaranteed to have well-defined behavior across all conforming C/C++ implementations is assigning to a variable of type `sig_atomic_t` and returning, e.g.:

```
sig_atomic_t flag = 0;

// This signal handler has well-defined behavior
void my_signal_handler(int signum)
{
    flag = 1;
}

int main(void)
{
    signal(SIGINT, &my_signal_handler);

    while(1)
    {
        doStuff();
        if(flag)
        {
            flag = 0;
            actuallyHandleSignalNow();
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Although in practice, you can almost always get away with doing a little more inside your signal handler.

Answer (score 1):

For `std::vector` that should be sufficient. I don't think anything guarantees that though. Memory allocation is considered an implementation detail. If you can restrict yourself to a specific size, I suggest going with a simple static array instead. That way, you have a fine-grained control over what exactly happens.

Comment: vector will be allocated dynamically,. no matter what you do, as will the things it contains.

Comment: Neil: If you have a vector with some preallocated items and you change an item, it won't result in memory allocation (this is not guaranteed by standard though, as I said).

Comment: Post some code that does what you suggest. Any use of vector (apart possibly from creating an empty one) will result in dynamic allocation. This is guaranteed by the standard.

Comment: `/*outside interrupt handler (this *does* result in allocation):*/ vector<int> x; x.push_back(10); /*inside interrupt handler (not likely to allocate anything:*/ x[0] = 0;

Comment: That in no way addresses the question.

Comment: Neil: That was my understanding of *Is it enough to create structure with predefined size and then avoid push/pop/erase calls?* in the OP. I might be wrong however.

Comment: Creating a vector of predefined size will result in dynamic allocation, either using new or whatever mechanism a user-supplied allocator provides for the vector and the things it contains - there is no way round this!

Comment: Of course. But you could **already have** the vector created somewhere else and just alter its contents in the interrupt handler.

Comment: If it is already created, it must have been created somehow! Vectors are inately dynamic - there is nom way of creating a vector that (for example) does static allocation for its internals. And if you alter its internals, you are open to more dynamic allocations.

Comment: It'll be created **outside** the interrupt handler where it's free to call `malloc` and other dynamic allocations. For example, think of a scenario that a `vector` represents a kernel process table where the interrupt handler would just set the process state flag from to `blocked`. I'm not saying that creating a vector with a predefined size doesn't result in dynamic allocation, from that sentence in the OP, I think he already has a preallocated vector to use. If he wants to **create** that in the interrupt handler, then yes, it'll result in dynamic allocation.

Comment: Sorry, you are right - I've realised I've completely misunderstood the question :-(